# Multipage PDF to TIFF result in wide pages with empty space

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, multipage

I have a multipage PDF file (which seems to have been created by Illustrator CS3 using Adobe PDF Library 8.0), which I want to convert to TIFF G3 using ImageMagick 6.8.6. Here is the result of the conversion `convert a1.pdf a1.tif` (I painted it red to hide details)
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

As you can see, in each page I get a wide page (as wide as 4 pages) and the actual image of each page is gradually shifted to the left, page-by-page.

This is the PDF info:

```
>identify a1.pdf
a1.pdf[0] PDF 3402x1134 3402x1134+0+0 16-bit sRGB 11.57MB 0.063u 0:00.062
a1.pdf[1] PDF 3402x1134 3402x1134+0+0 16-bit sRGB 11.57MB 0.047u 0:00.061
a1.pdf[2] PDF 3402x1134 3402x1134+0+0 16-bit sRGB 11.57MB 0.031u 0:00.046
a1.pdf[3] PDF 3402x1134 3402x1134+0+0 16-bit sRGB 11.57MB 0.016u 0:00.031
```

I tried to convert to `.jpg`, `.png` but I get the same behavior. I also tried ghostscript, the result is the same (obviously, as IM uses GS for PDF).

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please attach the file?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as it is a customers' data. But, I added some info, if can help.

Comment: You really need to share an example, maybe you can ask your customer to create a blank similar file. You also haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to tell without a sample file. You may try other convertors and  compare. Just type "pdf rasterizer" in google to find a bunch.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I tried a commercial converter and it worked.